# Keep specific columns in a data.frame while unlisting a column which is a data.frame type

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a data.frame called StockWeights. The structure of the data.frame is as follows:

```
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Id       : chr  "159347" "161863" "22646"
 $ ISIN     : chr  "DK0061156759" "DK0061533726" "DK0060681468"
 $ $id      : chr  "21" "22" "23"
 $ Name     : chr  "159347" "161863" "22646"
 $ SumPeriod:'data.frame':  3 obs. of  27 variables:
  ..$ AccPeriodBasTwrAtMarketPrice   : num  0.0969 0.538 -0.1071
  ..$ AccPeriodLocTwrAtMarketPrice   : num  0.0969 0.538 -0.1071
  ..$ BopDate                        : chr  "2022-02-28T00:00:00" "2022-02-28T00:00:00" "2022-02-28T00:00:00"
  ..$ BopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice: num  7592267 5135961 7166816
```

My question is then: How can I "unlist" this SumPeriod data.frame column and display the BopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice column together with the Id and ISIN columns? What I have done so far is to use the pluck function in the purrr package as such:

```
StockWeights  %>%
  pluck('SumPeriod') %>% 
  select("EopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice")
```

Which only gives me the "EopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice":

```
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ EopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice: num  7599626 5163591 7159142
```

But I can't find a way to get theese three values together with the corresponding "Id" and "ISIN" in the original data.frame. Anyone got an idea how to achieve this? Sorry for not producing a reproducible code. The data I am looking at is made from an API call and I am having some trouble in recreating it manually. But the end goal is to get a data.frame that looks like:

```
df = data.frame(
  Id = c("159347", "161863", "22646"),
  ISIN = c("DK0061156759", "DK0061533726", "DK0060681468"),
    BopBasHoldingValueAtMarketPrice = c(7592267,5135961,7166816)
  )
```

Comment: check tidyr::unnest